# Create a Random Heap from a List

Tags: list, haskell, heap

i'm doing some college studying in haskell atm, and im stuck at this. The data type is the following:

```
data Heap a = Empty | Node a (Heap a) (Heap a)
```

(in this exercise `Heap` a is always a min-max heap, therefore each node at an even level in the tree is less than all of its descendants, while each node at an odd level in the tree is greater than all of its descendants).

The Question:

> "`randomHeap :: [a] -> IO (Heap a)` which generates a random heap, containing all the elements from the argument list.
>
> "Use the function `randomRIO :: Random t => (t,t) -> IO t` (which is present in `System.Random`) to calculate a random value within a certain range.
>
> "Note that for a non empty list, the choice of which element to use for the root is unique, what should vary are which elements are used to build the sub-trees."

Comment: Well, my thought process was: generate a list using randomRIO from (0,30), through a function that receives an lnt (which is the length of the list to generate) , then my problem is getting the generated (sorted) list, into an heap. Maybe my problem is just syntax-wise.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? It's not at all clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume the heap shall be selected uniformly at random from all possibilities. Let's investigate the number `f(n)` of possibile min-max heaps with `n` nodes. A uniquely determined node goes at the root, there is no choice in this. We choose a subset of the remaining nodes to go on the left side, then repeat this for both children. `f(n+1) = sum_{k=0}^{n}{(n over k) * f(k) * f(n-k)}; f(0) = 0`. The first few terms are 1, 1, 2, 6, 24 and 120, which suggests the factorial sequence (and the proof of sequence equality is child's play), which also describes the number of possible orders of our input list. Therefore we can hope that each list order corresponds to a min-max heap.

Having mulled on it for a few minutes, it now seems obvious that after shuffling the list, we can split it at its minimum element, choosing the part of the list on the minimum's left as the mentioned subset, then splitting each half at the maximum element, then splitting each quarter at the minimum element, and so on. Different list orders yield different heaps, so this finite correspondence is one-to-one.

Comment: I'll try to implement that later today and I'll give the feedback thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably confused in the definition of heap.

You must chose the root which is the max/min element of the argument, depending on the type of heap. Than use the randomRIO to choose which elements go to each node.

Comment: He specifically said that the heap is a min-max heap. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap